# Motion Planning Packages

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All, I was wondering if there are any 2D motion planning packages available in ROS. The purpose is to control iRobot based on a given map and a point of destination. I tried searching through the available packages but they all seem to be related to path planning for a robotic arm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40525/motion-planning-packages/) by [swingingiant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2972/swingingiant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is the navigation stack:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0